# Preventing deadlock in "INSERT IF NOT EXISTS" in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to insert data into a database, but first I check if each row exists using a lookup, similar to the method suggested here:
[How to prevent SSIS from importing data from a file that already exist in database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10313612/how-to-prevent-ssis-from-importing-data-from-a-file-that-already-exist-in-databa)

```
SELECT DISTINCT VALUES    // OleDb Source
         |
       LOOKUP             // If exists
         |                // No Match Output
  OLE DB DESTINATION      // Insert new records
```

I'm using `RetainSameConnection=True` to enable transactions on my workflow. With a default buffer around 10,000 rows, as rows get passed to the OLE DB Destination, the destination `INSERT` will lock with the lookup `SELECT`.

I've tried `SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON`, which will work, but performance during the lookup is now incredibly slow, which I believe is due to the RetainSameConnection property, and I can't tell that SSIS is even using the READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT isolation level. I thought about ignoring failures on the destination, but I read it will cause bulk inserts to fail completely instead of by row. I've also considered using NOLOCK on all the reads, but it would turn all my lookups into SQL queries.

The source DB may read millions of rows. **Is there a better way to accomplish this?**

Comment: What cache did you choose for your lookup? How do you have your ole db destination configured? Can your Source have duplicates internally? I see you have `DISTINCT` applied but could the lookup generate the same key for dissimilar rows within the same set? What data volumes are in your source vs destination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is getting into the area where the answers are going to be based more on preference and experience than there just being one easily defined way of doing this. There will likely be a good number of answers which will show different methodologies that might work for you, but the basics of any of these are going be based around a couple of things

1. Reducing the number of rows that are saved in your lookup during pre-caching of the data flow task

   Generally speaking, the values for all lookups are populated before the data flow begins to execute and read data from the source based on the configuration of the lookup. If you have your SSIS configured this way, then there should not be any contention between the lookup and the insertion of rows into your table regardless of isolation level.

   Based on what you said above, I'm thinking that perhaps the performance of the lookup is not changing drastically because of your configurations but more because the amount of data being cached into the lookup is increasing with each execution.
2. Changing the Lookup pattern to use a different pattern

   The most basic implementation of the lookup is usually fine for most cases. However, if performance is a heavy concern for package execution then there may be other more ideal methods to accomplishing the same objective. One of these which I talk about in my blog refers to using a merge join as an alternative to the standard lookup. This may not be ideal for your situation as I designed this particular strategy to cover a corner case involving large data sets, but hopefully it should give you some ideas.

   I have a fairly detailed walkthrough of that pattern at the link below

   https://web.archive.org/web/20140819083150/http://bigdatabigdave.info/archive/2013/02/15/alternate-ssis-lookup-pattern-merge-join/

Comment: I can see a merge join replacing regular lookups, but in the above case of just using it for "INSERT IF NOT EXISTS" where I'm not selecting any columns, I can't see how it's applicable.

Comment: @WillEddins There's functionally no difference between a lookup and a lookup existing other than adding an additional column. In terms of methodology they are extremely similar. It's merely presented here as an example of an alternative lookup pattern to demonstrate the point.

Answer (score 0):

One place I remember they wrote all the insert lines to a raw file.  Then there was a second dataflow (after the first dataflow finished) that inserted the raw file records into the destination table.